# How many Vaults are there in Fallout game universe?

Tags: fallout

In the Fallout lore, I have gathered information that there are 112 vaults. But is that all of them or just the vaults that have been released as in-game content? Wouldn't there be other vaults in the other countries across the Atlantic?  
 
So overall, how many Vaults are there?

Comment: If you consider the new Fallout Shelter mobile game canon, 1000 ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, there are a total of [122 Vaults](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault) in the US in the Fallout Universe.

> Commissioned by the U.S. government in 2054 as part of “Project: Safehouse”, the Vault-Tec Corporation constructed 122 Vaults across the country

6 are available to explore in Fallout 3, listed [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_3_locations) on the official Fallout 3 wiki in the Vaults section.

7 are available to explore in New Vegas, listed [here](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_locations) on the official New Vegas wiki in the Vaults section.

And I can't comment for sure about Vaults outside the US. The Vaults were an American initiative, other countries probably did something similar but I don't think it's ever mentioned in-game.

Comment: Also [Vault 77](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault_77), which was populated only by one man and a crate of puppets.

Answer (score 1):

Vault Tech Corporation was only capable of constructing a maximum of 112 vaults. Unfortunately, due to the size of the population and the overall effects the Wars had- had on the  economy; Vault Tech was not able to afford to build more vaults. Although, that being said. There were a number of 'Private Vaults' constructed; but unfortunately  the contents and whereabouts of those vaults are relatively unknown.

Aside from a few control vaults, whose functionality mirrored the official promise. Most of the vaults were testing grounds for social experiments. The types of experiments could vary from Subliminal messaging, Controlled Genetic Mutation, Isolation and even Sexual Predatory Instinct (Speculation based on Vault 68 and 69).

Answer (score 0):

There were about 122 vaults constructed as Vault-Tec wasn't interested in preserving the human race, rather doing ion them, with the exception with "control" vaults like Vault 101 and Vault 76.

Each state had at maximum two vaults, (with the exeption of vaults in the Capital Wasteland, Commonwealth, Mojave Wasteland, and New California).

If Vault-Tec wanted to preserve most of the human race, Vault-Tec would need to build at least 1,000,000 vaults.

Answer (score -4):

[Here is a list of all the American Vaults](http://vault-tec.weebly.com/vaults.html).
I don't think that there are 112 vaults, probably much less than that.
as you see in the American vaults list the numbers don't come after each other. That might be intentional or it might mean that the "missing" numbers are vaults made in Europe, Africa etc...

Comment: That's just a list of vaults that were already mentioned by number - doesn't suggest that there couldn't be more, not yet seen in game.

Answer (score -8):

To correct many of the false answers, I believe only around 240 vaults were made, in approx. The vaults were not going to be used as protective shelters for the way, but to preform social experiments. Each vault has their own experiment with the exception of a few "control" vaults, actually designed to do as the people were told. The "cry wolf effect" happened when the bombs actually fell, and people used them as shelters. They did not build enough vaults for every American citizen, as they had not nearly enough money for it all. According to know game lure, Vault-tec, the creators of the vaults, was only in the US, and no vaults were build a anywhere else. I hope this covers it all, thank you!

Comment: Could you add references to where that information comes from please?